# about combinations of tcp flags porblem

Tags: wireshark

I know that the data is being sent with the psh flag, but the wireshark I captured seems to lack one of the ack responses.

It does not seem to be a loss of data.

Can you explain why I do not have one ack message

[image]

Answer (score 0):

TCP doesn't require ack'ing every packet individually; it uses a "sliding window" mechanism that allows the source to send multiple segments at once and the recipient to only need ac­knowl­edging the highest one.

So in your case, if the three segments (seq 1, seq 3, seq 5) were received at once, it is enough to reply with "ack 5" and *all* previous segments are considered acknowledged from that.